# Node.js req.body socket writing

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, body-parser

I have a small Node.js webapp that should broadcast post messages via sockets. The main problem here is, that the req.body part of the post is of type Object. Converting via the toString() function only converts the typename, so you only see "object":

```
req.body.toString()
"[object Object]"
```

con is a dict.js dictionary. Very nice, by the way. The sockets are in the value-part of the con dict.

Here the post code:

```
router.post('/message', function (req, res) {
    con.forEach(function (value, key) {
        if (key != user) {
            debug("BROADCAST: " + user + " -> " + key);
            value.write(req.body);
        }
    });
    var answer = "[{\"urls\":\"here_be_dragons"}]";
    res.send(answer);
});
```

I also tried bodyParser, but typeof(req.body) always returns "object" (although it probably should do it, when I set router.use(bodyParser.text())):

```
typeof(req.body)
"object"
```

I also can see that the information in the req.body object is correct.

So my question is: How can I get req.body to a string type with the correct information?

Comment: dist.js? do you mean an object?

Comment: It's actually [dict.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dict). I just wanted to clarify, what the object name "con" is.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with the querystring module!

```
var qs = require('querystring');
```

The stringify and unescape methods worked for me:

```
value.write(qs.unescape(qs.stringify(req.body)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the JSON representation instead. For that you can just do: `JSON.stringify(req.body);`

Comment: Already tried that. Something very very strange happens: The resulting message is a JSON with the object of the req.body inserted in the key-part of the JSON. Very very strange.

Comment: If that's the case then you're probably using the wrong `Content-Type` in the request. I'm betting that the request data contains JSON but the request has `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.